# Google Search Console can't index my React Webapp

Tags: google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, google-search-console

I have a web app built with react, and is hosted on Firebase's Hosting, and served with cloud functions.

An example of serving the index.html from cloud functions, is changing the .htaccess:

```
"rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "[functionThatReturnsIndex.html]"
      }
    ],
```

I export the build, and then I serve the index.html from a function, which works fine.

I do this, so I can dynamically set the META tags for each page.

This both loads fine, and when I share a link on a site, like twitter/linkedin/facebook etc., the META information that those websites fetch is also correct and as expected.

However, I'm getting an error (redirect error) from the search console, when trying to index my site.

It suggested I use Lighthouse in the chrome web tools to test what's wrong, and I got decent results:

[image]

This is my robots.txt:

```
# https://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

I'm not sure what else to try, or why it's not indexing. Any help would be appreciated.

Let me know if I can provide more information to make the solution more obvious, thank you.

**Update 1:**

[image]

Comment: I'm not an expert on this case, but I'd like to help, so what I found on google's support doc  is this https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7440203?hl=en#zippy=%2Cerror-spikes:~:text=server%20errors.-,Redirect%20error,-Google%20experienced%20one. So clue 1 is the issue is in the URL being indexed. Could you share the error message so I could try some more?

Comment: @HasanRiza thank you! I've updated the question with the only error I get. Screenshot at the bottom.

Comment: I hope I'm not bothering you with my trial and error, but I found this https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7474347?hl=en#:~:text=If%20your%20site%20or%20page%20is%20new, a suggestion in the verification part is to add a sitemap, do you think that would help in this case?

Comment: thing about the sitemap is most of the pages, apart from the default ones, are dynamic/user-created. So I want google to index new profiles as they're discovered. I don't think it's scalable to make a sitemap for such a situation

Comment: That is exactly the type of situation where sitemaps help the most.  You would regenerate the sitemap periodically (say every night) from your database.  That would allow search engines to discover all your new pages more quickly.  However sitemaps don't usually help those pages get indexed or ranked well.  See [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox)

Comment: When Google search console shows a "redirect error,"  it usually means that the page is redirecting back to itself. If you paste the URL for the page into a new private browsing windows in your browser, do you see the page?

Comment: Have you tried a "live test" in the Google search console inspection tool?  Have you clicked on the "Viewed crawled page" link the provide to see the screenshots and DOM that Googlebot sees?

Comment: Have you implemented server side rendering (SSR)?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I did a live test on the url and everything seemed to work, "URL is available to Google
If it gets indexed and selected as canonical, it could appear in Google Search results with all relevant enhancements. Learn more
Page changed?
check_circle
Page availability
Page can be indexed
Enhancements and experience
Mobile Usability
Page is usable on mobile"

I'm going to wait till it tried to index it again, ive sent a request, and I'll see if it returns the same error. If the live test works, and the other test doesn't, i might need to get help from google

Answer (score -2):

They are 2 types of Sitemaps viz: Static and Dynamic Sitemaps.

In your case, you need a Dynamic Sitemap to discover dynamically created contents in your React App automatically.

I'll suggest you use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dynamic-sitemap
to implement a dynamic sitemap and submit the resulting Sitemap URL to Google.

Hope this helps you in fixing this error.

Comment: Sitemaps won't help an indexing problem.  Sitemaps help Google find newly posted URLs quickly.  Googlebot will then come and crawl those pages.  However, URLs that are only found through sitemaps rarely get indexed at all, let alone ranked well.  See [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox)